# Is there a way to get driveID from onedrive for business url using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

Say my Onedrive for business URL is https://mysharepoint-my.sharepoint.com. Is there a Graph API to get driveID using this URL?
There is currently a 2 hop solution. We can get the site ID using sites/sitesURL, then using the site ID, we can fetch the driveID. But this solution is not working if I have a `-my` in my URL.

Comment: No, but why not just use `/me/drive` to retrieve the user's OneDrive metadata?

Comment: I'm trying to access onedrive for subsites, like `https://mysharepoint-my.sharepoint.com/subsiteinSPO`

Comment: If you're able to address a site, you can append `/drive` to get the default drive under it. Does that work for you? If not, can you give a more-specific example of the 2-hop solution you currently have?